# Where did the apple that Altair hides in the library come from?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations, assassins-creed-series

I've just finished my first play-through revelations yesterday, and something is bothering me since.

> It's about the apple which Altair hides in the library with him. Where did it come from? It can't be the same one from the previous games, because this one is still there when Ezio opens the library (I think). And if there are many apples, then why didn't the templars found them?

Is there something that I've missed? (It's not impossible, as I was already quite tired and sleepy by the end).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This whole answer is chock full of spoilers about the AC universe and story.  Hopefully you already knew this from the huge spoiler tag in the question.  :)

There *are* multiple Pieces of Eden in the Assassin's Creed universe.  The Templars are searching for them in the first game, which is why they're curious about Desmond's memories of Altair - at the end of the first game he holds the Piece of Eden and it displays a globe with locations marked.  These are the locations of other Pieces of Eden.

In some of the "secret" memories that you can use to unlock "The Truth" in the series, you're told that Pieces of Eden have influenced or allowed great leaders from history to rise to power.  The Templars plan to use many Pieces of Eden, in concert with a vast amplification network, to extend their control over the entire world at once.

The Piece of Eden that Ezio locates in Assassin's Creed 2 is different from the one Altair had - this one the Templars have already recovered from wherever it had been previously hidden or kept.  Ezio takes it from the Templars twice, and finally hides it for Desmond and the Assassin team to recover later in AC: Brotherhood.  (This is the piece Desmond takes right before stabbing Lucy)

At the end of Revelations, Ezio recovers Altair's Piece of Eden, which Altair had possessed from the end of the events of the first game until his death.  The memories that Ezio recovers from the library keys tell the story of how this device effected the assassin brotherhood in the years following the original game.

Comment: I knew about the multiple POEs (like the papal staff), but I thought each one is unique, again like the apple and the papal staff. I'll try to find out more later today.

Comment: @ivant The top of the staff is actually an "apple" POE - I don't know if they've all got different powers or not.  I had assumed they were all pretty similar, based on the way Altair and Ezio use their different pieces at different points in the series.

Comment: Wow! It seems there are at least 5 apples http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Piece_of_eden#Confirmed_Pieces_of_Eden

Comment: wasn't there a mention of a number in the first or second games? Thought it was meant to be about 12 or so? Ooh actually that would tie in to the whole First Civilisation/Gods of Olympus thing, but not sure if I just made that number up :/ Can anyone verify?